# PDF file not found but correct location?

Tags: reactjs, react-pdf

I'm trying to display a PDF on a website. I'm using the package react-pdf. My component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';

export default function Resume() {
    return (
        <Document file="../../resume.pdf">
            <Page />
        </Document>
    )
}
```

I'm getting this error on the webpage when the component renders:

```
Failed to load PDF file.
```

My path should be correct. The directory is like this:

```
src/
  app.js
  index.js
  resume.pdf
  components/
    Resume/
      index.js
```

Could this be an issue with the PDF itself? The PDF is a file I wrote as html/css and Saved As a PDF.

Comment: check your webpack config, you should be copying the pdf file to the output build like in the example https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/blob/master/sample/webpack/webpack.config.js#L48

Comment: using create-react-app will this cause error in production?

Comment: yeah I think, maybe the pdf should go in the public folder https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/#adding-assets-outside-of-the-module-system
verify that the pdf is being added in the build and so on

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this question I ended up ditching the react-pdf package. I only need to view the pdf so I just used the embed tag like such:

```
<embed src={require('../../file.pdf'} />
```